# Estimating the cumulative probability of a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, pearson-r, bivariate, numerical-integration

I have a quick question regarding working out the probabilities of a bivariate normal distribution. To my knowledge, there is no nice closed-form for a cumulative distribution function for the bivariate normal distribution ([Botev, 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.04166)) so instead, we must numerically integrate through the bivariate normal distribution's probability density function (I think?).

I am referring to this thing in particular: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html

So how is this done? By using the trapezoid rule or Simpson's rule? Or would that be an incorrect approach and a more accurate one is called for?

**EDIT:** a user pointed out a paper by [Drzner & Welowosky (2010)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949659008811236) which discusses numerical methods to integrate over a univariate distribution. This user also pointed out to me that the c.d.f. for this kind of distribution is

$$ \mathbb P(X<x,Y<y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\mathbb P(Y<y|X=x)\varphi(x;\mu_X,\sigma_X)\text dx $$

Comment: What do you mean by "not yet discovered"? The multivariate cdf is well-defined as$$\mathbb P(X<x,Y<y)=\int_{-\infty}^x\mathbb P(Y<y|X=x)\varphi(x;\mu_X,\sigma_X)\text dx$$and as a univariate integral can be accurately evaluated by numerical methods. See, eg, [Drzner&Welowosky (2010)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00949659008811236)

Comment: Oh thank you @Xi'an --- I said "to my knowledge," but I'm not familiar with that paper :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a screen-shot from [Mark Schervish's (1984) paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347670?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) on the approximation of the multivariate Normal probability function, based on (recursive) quadrature formulae, where
$$G_L(x_N,\ldots,X_{N-L+1})=\int_{A(L)}^{B(L)}\cdots\int_{A(1)}^{B(1)} f(x_1,\ldots,x_N)\,\text dx_1\cdots\text dx_N$$
is the $L$-th inner integral.
[image]

[Schervish (1984)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347670?seq=2#metadata_info_tab_contents) also provides a formula for the choice of the errors $\delta_L$ $(L=1,\ldots, N-2)$ towards the overall numerical error being at most $\epsilon$.